# Nearest neightbour interpolation mode in OpenTK exist?

Tags: c#, opentk

If I draw a low resolution bitmap to a big area with `System.Drawing.Graphics` and changing it's `InterpolationMode` to `InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor`, it looks pixelated.
And I want to achive the same result using OpenTK.

I have tried resizing the image files to a higher resolution using paint.net's nearest neightbour function on resize, and I got the expected results. But I don't want to resize every single image, and it uses more space on the disk and I guess more RAM in the application.

This is the texture loading method that I use for my application, and with that, my low-res image looks blury:

```
public static int LoadTexture(Bitmap bmp)
{
GL.Enable(EnableCap.Texture2D);

int tex;
GL.Hint(HintTarget.PerspectiveCorrectionHint, HintMode.Nicest);

GL.GenTextures(1, out tex);
GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, tex);

BitmapData data = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height),
    ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
GL.TexImage2D(TextureTarget.Texture2D, 0, PixelInternalFormat.Rgba, data.Width, data.Height, 0,
    OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.PixelFormat.Bgra, PixelType.UnsignedByte, data.Scan0);
bmp.UnlockBits(data);

GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMinFilter, (int)TextureMinFilter.Linear);
GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMagFilter, (int)TextureMagFilter.Linear);
GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureWrapS, (int)TextureWrapMode.Repeat);
GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureWrapT, (int)TextureWrapMode.Repeat);

return tex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The filter to `TextureMinFilter` and `TextureMagFilter` needs to be `Nearest` instead of `Linear`.
So you need to replace these lines:

```
GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMinFilter, (int)TextureMinFilter.Linear);
GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMagFilter, (int)TextureMagFilter.Linear);
```

to these:

```
GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMinFilter, (int)TextureMinFilter.Nearest);
GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMagFilter, (int)TextureMagFilter.Nearest);
```